# CSS - include scrollbar size in margin

Tags: html, css

I'm building a layout for an email inbox. The given design consists of a header and a inbox-wrap with a scrollbar on the very right. The inbox within shall have the same width like the header. As browser scrollbars can have differ from the width, the inbox margin-right can be different from the header margin-right, that has no scrollbar. Is there an improvement possible without JS, that aligns header and inbox?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e88Rj/5/)

HTML

```
<div class="header"> HEADER</div>

  <div class="inbox_wrap">

    <div class="inbox">
       Item<br />
       Item<br />...
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header{
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.inbox_wrap{
  background:  rgba(111,111,111,0.2);
  left: 40px;
  right: 0;
  top: 80px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inbox{
     background: rgb(100,200,240);
     margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Without targeting each browser (and operating system for that matter) specifically, no. Then you have the issue of users on OSX with a Magic Mouse. They don't display a visible scrollbar, and just indicate the scroll handle when the user actually scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

you can "include" the width of the scrollbar by using the inbox-wrap for scrolling. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/e88Rj/4/

```
html, body
{
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header{
    height: 50px;
    background: grey;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    color: white;
}

.inbox_wrap{
    background:  rgba(111,111,111,0.2);
    left: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    top: 80px;
    bottom:0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.inbox{
    background: rgb(100,200,240);
}
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot the design is asking for rounded borders [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e88Rj/5/) , these would disappear

Comment: when you think rounded borders are more important than clear scrollbars, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/e88Rj/6/

Comment: @user3260177 i forgot do name you. see the fiddle in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to understand to your question but if you want to align the header and inbox then visit on [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazshah/2suDB/) where I have aligned the both div.

```
<div class="header"> HEADER</div>

  <div class="inbox_wrap">

    <div class="inbox">
       Item<br />
       Item<br />...
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the scrollbar width differs according to the browser, you cannot hard code the margin-right [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2suDB/1/)